# select a part of dataframe every time in parallel

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, multithreading, multiprocessing

I want to create dictionaries in a loop.

Since, in every iteration I am taking only a part of the initial dataframe ( `df_train = df[df['CLASS'] == oneClass]`) , I want to make it parallel.

My code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,1,2], 'b':[3, 4, 5], 'c': [6, 7, 8], 'CLASS':['A', 'B', 'C']})


def make_dataframes(df, oneClass):
    new_df = {}
    df_train = df[df['CLASS'] == oneClass]
    numeric_only_data_cols = df_train.select_dtypes(include=np.number).columns.difference(['CLASS'])
    numeric_only_data = df_train[numeric_only_data_cols]

    X = numeric_only_data.values
    x = X * 100
    
    orig_columns = numeric_only_data.loc[:, 
                                         numeric_only_data.columns!='CLASS'].columns
   
    new_df[oneClass] = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=orig_columns)
    new_df[oneClass]['CLASS'] = df_train['CLASS']
    
    return new_df
        

new_df = {}
classes = np.unique(df['CLASS'])
with Pool(4) as pool:
    for new_dataframe in pool.map(make_dataframes, classes):
        new_df['new_dataframe'] = new_dataframe
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
```

I omitted the for loop in the function:

```
new_df = {}
for oneClass in classes:
    df_train = df[df['GROUP_DESC'] == oneClass]
    ...
```

Now, I am receiving:

```
make_dataframes() missing 1 required positional argument: 'oneClass'
```

I am not sure how to place the arguments of the function and if the `classes` is a valid argument for `map`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you planning on executing your code inside a cluster? If not, then you're probably better off executing your code in the old single process fashioned way. There's this great talk on the subject by Raymond Hettinger that I find pretty interesting, and I recommend checking out: [Raymond Hettinger, Keynote on Concurrency, PyBay 2017](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9zinZmE3Ogk).

Having said that, one easy fix to your implementation would be to define a single parameter as input to `make_dataframes`, that represents a tuple of both `df`, and `oneClass`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool


def make_dataframes(args):

    new_df = {}

    df = args[0]        # <--- Unpacking values
    oneClass = args[-1] # <--- Unpacking values

    df_train = df[df['CLASS'] == oneClass]
    numeric_only_data = df_train.select_dtypes(include=np.number).loc[:, lambda xdf: xdf.columns.difference(['CLASS'])]

    X = numeric_only_data.values
    x = X * 100
    
    orig_columns = numeric_only_data.loc[:, numeric_only_data.columns != 'CLASS'].columns
    new_df[oneClass] = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=orig_columns)
    new_df[oneClass]['CLASS'] = df_train['CLASS']
    return new_df


df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,1,2], 'b':[3, 4, 5], 'c': [6, 7, 8], 'CLASS':['A', 'B', 'C']})
new_df = {}
classes = np.unique(df["CLASS"])
with Pool(4) as pool:
    for new_dataframe in pool.map(make_dataframes, zip([df]*len(classes), classes)):
        new_df[list(new_dataframe.keys())[0]] = list(new_dataframe.values())[0]
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
```

A second approach would be to use the [Joblib](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/) package instead of `multiprocessing`, like so:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from joblib import Parallel, delayed


def make_dataframes(df, oneClass):
    new_df = {}
    df_train = df[df["CLASS"] == oneClass]
    numeric_only_data = df_train.select_dtypes(include=np.number).loc[
        :, lambda xdf: xdf.columns.difference(["CLASS"])
    ]

    X = numeric_only_data.values
    x = X * 100

    orig_columns = numeric_only_data.loc[
        :, numeric_only_data.columns != "CLASS"
    ].columns
    new_df[oneClass] = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=orig_columns)
    new_df[oneClass]["CLASS"] = df_train["CLASS"]
    return new_df


df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,1,2], 'b':[3, 4, 5], 'c': [6, 7, 8], 'CLASS':['A', 'B', 'C']})

classes = np.unique(df["CLASS"])

new_df = {
    key: value
    for parallel in Parallel(n_jobs=4)(
        delayed(make_dataframes)(df, i) for i in classes
    )
    for key, value in parallel.items()
}
```

Finally, the approach I recommend using, if you're not planning on running this code inside a power-hungry cluster, and need to extract all the juice you can get from it:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from joblib import Parallel, delayed


def make_dataframes(df, oneClass):
    new_df = {}
    df_train = df[df["CLASS"] == oneClass]
    numeric_only_data = df_train.select_dtypes(include=np.number).loc[
        :, lambda xdf: xdf.columns.difference(["CLASS"])
    ]

    X = numeric_only_data.values
    x = X * 100

    orig_columns = numeric_only_data.loc[
        :, numeric_only_data.columns != "CLASS"
    ].columns
    new_df[oneClass] = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=orig_columns)
    new_df[oneClass]["CLASS"] = df_train["CLASS"]
    return new_df


df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,1,2], 'b':[3, 4, 5], 'c': [6, 7, 8], 'CLASS':['A', 'B', 'C']})
classes = np.unique(df["CLASS"])
new_df = {c: make_dataframes(df, c)[c] for c in classes}
```

For comparison, I've recorded each approach execution time:

- `multiprocessing`: CPU times: user 13.6 ms, sys: 41.1 ms, total: 54.7 ms **Wall time: 158 ms**
- `joblib`: CPU times: user 14.3 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 14.3 ms **Wall time: 16.5 ms**
- `Serial processing`: CPU times: user 14.1 ms, sys: 797 µs, total: 14.9 ms **Wall time: 14.9 ms**

Running things in parallel has a lot of overhead communication costs between the different processing nodes. Besides it's an intrinsically more complex task to do, then to run things serially. Consequently, developing and maintaining the code becomes exponentially harder and expensive. If running things in parallel is number 1 priority, I would recommend first ditching Pandas, and using [PySpark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/getting_started/index.html), or [Dask](https://www.dask.org/) instead.

Comment: I don't want to execute a heavy task. Just a task where the initial dataframe contains many thousand of lines. Thanks for the solutions!! (upv)

Comment: Hi, I am using the second, joblib approach and I use `cpu_count = len(psutil.Process().cpu_affinity())` . So , `for parallel in Parallel(n_jobs=cpu_count)(`. But, for a second, it starts to use all cpus and then immediately drops only to two and then to one. Do you happen to know this issue?

Comment: Basically, I may be running operations that cannot be parallelized.

Comment: @George that's probably the case. To give an example, if you try to paralyze the sum of all elements of a vector, you could start the process with an army of nodes doing little parts of the operation. The thing is, that when these nodes finish up their processes, they need to send (or receive) their output to another node and at the end, the last part of the sum can only be done by one of these nodes. The operation you're trying to do has a similar fate. Another important factor is that these communications that nodes need to perform have a big effect on the processing time.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. I am using a sklearn library inside the code, so this is the issue.Thanks!